# My SELECT clause inside my postgres ARRAY() function seems to not be building the correct array syntax

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I am building a array from a select clause in my `WHERE` condition

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM users AS u 
INNER JOIN microposts m ON u.id=m.user_id 
INNER JOIN taggings t ON m.id=t.taggable_id 
INNER JOIN tags t2 ON t2.id=t.tag_id 
WHERE ARRAY(SELECT name FROM tags)::text[] @> ARRAY['hello']
```

The problem part is `WHERE ARRAY(SELECT name FROM tags)::text[]`

This line works ok if I compare it to a single value eg `ARRAY['hello']`

But if it's more than one value and my `ARRAY(SELECT name FROM tags)::text[]` should be building the same array as `ARRAY['hello', 'gday']`  it is not working.

Is my `ARRAY(SELECT name FROM tags)::text[]` statement building the correct array? if not how come?

**For clarity here is my data structure**

Microposts

```
╔════════════════╤════════════════════╤═══════════╗
║ id             │ user_id            │ content   ║
╠════════════════╪════════════════════╪═══════════╣
║ 1              │ 2                  │ "hi"      ║
╟────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ 2              │ 2                  │ "gday"    ║
╟────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ 3              │ 1                  │ "yo"      ║
╟────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ 4              │ 1                  │ "mate"    ║
╚════════════════╧════════════════════╧═══════════╝
```

Taggings. NOTE: taggable_id is the microposts.id

```
╔════════════════╤════════════════════╤═══════════╗
║ id             │ taggable_id        │ tag_id    ║
╠════════════════╪════════════════════╪═══════════╣
║ 1              │ 1                  │ 1         ║
╟────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ 2              │ 1                  │ 2         ║
╟────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ 3              │ 1                  │ 3         ║
╟────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ 4              │ 2                  │ 3         ║
╚════════════════╧════════════════════╧═══════════╝
```

Tags table

```
╔════════════════╤════════════╗
║ id             │ name       ║
╠════════════════╪════════════╣
║ 1              │  "sport"   ║
╟────────────────┼────────────╢
║ 2              │  "cats"    ║
╟────────────────┼────────────╢
║ 3              │  "bird"    ║
╟────────────────┼────────────╢
║ 4              │  "diving"  ║
╚════════════════╧════════════╝
```

**EDITTTT:** Ok example

User input is `ARRAY['sport', 'cats', 'bird']`

So based on our tables this correlates to give us `taggings.tag_id` 1, 2, 3 and each has a `taggings.taggable_id` of 1 which is a match to a micropost. So this is exactly what I am inputting.

Comment: The condition in your statement simply builds an array of all names in tags table, independent of anything else.  It selects from tags table without any restrictions so if there is a name "hello" anywhere, it resolves to true.  What exactly is the expected results?

Comment: I started to realise this. I actually want the tags to be selected from the JOIN tables created in my statement. I tried `ARRAY(SELECT name FROM t2)::text[]` but I got a error that that was not a valid relation. Expected results should return the microposts where its tags at-least contain the array from a user inputted array of tags. I do realize now if the user inputed array is larger than the microposts tags array then it wont return true? but I could always make two and reverse one...??

Comment: Like this `ARRAY['hello', 'gday'] @> ARRAY['hello', 'gday']` should return true and if tags is selecting from the tags table then my select statement should be true as there is tags in the db that are `gday` and `hello` even if they are not linked to the micropost.

Comment: Might be better to select correct tags and join them with posts: ```select distinct microposts.* from tags  
join taggings on taggings.tag_id=tags.id
join microposts on microposts.id=tagging.taggable_id
where tags.name = any(USERDEFINEDARRAY)```

Comment: Does it matter the order? Isn't the way I am doing still correct? And will any() just return if it contains any?

Comment: Based on your structure example, please show also example input tags and expected result,  like  you showed your tables (edit post and add there)

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.  It is not obvious.

Comment: added example..

Comment: Yes @LeeEather.  I probably misunderstood that point.  Look at answer given :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for microposts that have a particular collection of tags, then you need aggregation.  With arrays you could use:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM microposts m JOIN
     taggings tt
     ON m.id = tt.taggable_id JOIN
     tags t
     ON t.id = tt.tag_id 
GROUP BY m.id   -- allowed assuming id is either the primary key or unique
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(t.name ORDER BY t.name) @> ARRAY['hello'] ;
```

Comment: Ok great it is working great. I just added `ARRAY_AGG(t.name ORDER BY t.name)::text[]` to match type. thankyou.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do this conditionally eg if the user inputted string happens to be empty?

Comment: You can use a separate condition for that . . . `or cardinality(<ar>) = 0`.